# Error instaling rstan on Rstudio Server

Tags: r, installation, stan

We're having trouble trying to install rstan at our server running Rstudio (version 0.97).
We're using Ubuntu 12.10 ( x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)) and R 2.15.1.

I installed Rcpp_0.10.3 and inline_0.3.11. However, when I run

```
options(repos = c(getOption("repos"), rstan = "http://wiki.stan.googlecode.com/git/R"))
install.packages('rstan', type = 'source')
```

I get the following error:

```
g++: error: ***********HYPERATIVA**********: No such file or directory
g++: error: Analytics: No such file or directory
g++: error: Welcome: No such file or directory
g++: error: to: No such file or directory
g++: error: R!: No such file or directory
g++: error: ***********HYPERATIVA**********: No such file or directory
g++: error: Analytics: No such file or directory
g++: error: Goodbye!: No such file or directory
make: *** [rstan.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rstan’
* removing ‘/home/likewise-open/HYPERATIVANET/mgaldino/R/library/rstan’
```

However, these folders do exist and everything works fine with other packages.
Does any of you know what to do?

Comment: Can you verify that you can execute the "Hello World" example at https://code.google.com/p/stan/wiki/RStanGettingStarted#C++_compiler ? It looks as if you have some sort of customized startup banner that is perhaps generated by a Rprofile file that is interfering with the call to g++.

Comment: I just tryed it and it worked fine.

Comment: OK, what file causes RStudio to output "HYPERATIVA Analytics Welcome to R! on startup and "HYPERATIVA Analytics Goodbye!" on shutdown? The usual suspects are documented under `help(Startup)`. Also, it may be helpful to add the `INSTALL_opts='-d'` argument to `install_packages()` to obtain some debug information; e.g. `install.packages('rstan', type = 'source', repos = 'http://wiki.stan.googlecode.com/git/R', INSTALL_opts='-d')`.

Comment: If it is feasible to install R >= 3.0.1, then this error can most likely be circumvented by unsetting the environmental variables R_MAKEVARS_SITE and R_MAKEVARS_USER. For example, do `Sys.unsetenv('R_MAKEVARS_SITE')` and `Sys.unsetenv('R_MAKEVARS_USER')`. See the section entitled "Package Installation" in the release notes for R 3.0.1 and `help(Sys.unsetenv)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further review, this problem seems to be caused in versions of RStan <= 1.3.0 when a site-wide or user's Rprofile file contains `cat` calls such as "Welcome to R!". A possible workaround is to temporarily set the environmental variables R_PROFILE and R_PROFILE_USER to point to an empty file.

For plain R (not RStudio), execute in a bash shell:

```
touch /tmp/Rprofile
export R_PROFILE=/tmp/Rprofile
export R_PROFILE_USER=/tmp/Rprofile
R -e "install.packages('rstan', type='source',repos='http://wiki.stan.googlecode.com/git/R')"
export R_PROFILE=
export R_PROFILE_USER=
```

If RStudio is already running, execute the equivalent in RStudio:

```
system('touch /tmp/Rprofile')
Sys.setenv(R_PROFILE="/tmp/Rprofile")
Sys.setenv(R_PROFILE_USER="/tmp/Rprofile")
install.packages('rstan', type='source', repos='http://wiki.stan.googlecode.com/git/R')
Sys.unsetenv('R_PROFILE')
Sys.unsetenv('R_PROFILE_USER')
```

Comment: I tryed your code at RStudio and it worked. Thank you very much. Now it's time to try to fit some models with Stan (I'm really excited to see how powerful Stan is, since I had simulations running for half a day with Bugs during my PhD).